# Dynamically display content in a wiki page based on a selected item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, wiki

I am trying to organize a wiki page that will have a section of text, and then a series of sections where the reader only needs one piece, followed by more common content and more variable text. I have been thinking that tabs would be good but am open to other ideas.  Basically the content will be:

A section of generic text discussing the goal, A paragraph (or more) explaining the first step(s) to accomplish a task. Then, based on a Country, different instructions on how to do additional steps, then more common instruction that is independent of the country, then instruction that is dependent on an application being used.

So I thought I could have:

[image: Sample of the possible page layout]

I am trying to avoid editing HTML to create tabs as I want to make this as easy as possible for others to edit the content and especially add new Countries.  I also want this to be able to move to SharePoint 2013.  I have seen Easy Tabs and the newer SPELL items, and other Zone Tabs, but they all use web parts to define the tabs.  Accordion items are less appealing because there could be a large list of items. Could be a list item drop-down but a tab seems more user friendly.  Is there anything that wouldn't expect a future person editing the content to place a new web part to get a new tab. I am having them use Markup Styles for headings and am willing to have a web part that is the area that contains the tabs, maybe with the tabs generated based on heading styles.  I don't expect the people editing this to know about web parts, though. Since there is a WYSIWIG editor, Markup Styles will be too much for half the people editing this to deal with.

I am having a difficult time explaining what I am looking for so I hope you can floow all this and help out.

Regards,
Karl