# Dynamically Display List from Menu Selection

Tags: 2010, web-part

I currently have a site that has a CSS/HTML menu that links to different lists created in SharePoint 2010. There are dozens of these lists and currently selecting one from the menu goes to an entirely new page. I would like to dynamically call these lists via menu item is selected similar to what is being asked for here: [Dynamically display content in a wiki page based on a selected item](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85899/dynamically-display-content-in-a-wiki-page-based-on-a-selected-item)

Limtations: I do not have, nor can I get, access to Designer, JQuery or third party add ons. Has to be out of the box SP.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be done using OOTB SP. At least without using JQuery or SPD

Comment: You would need to run a query against your site colelction.  This requires code. +1

Comment: This menu contains links to 72 different lists. This means I have to create 72 different pages for each list...